# Docker Container url not accessible through localhost or ip on windows 10/docker CE/.net Core

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

This is most simple use case for using docker on windows to deploy dotnet core app.
I used visual studio 2017 to create a dotnet core api with docker support enabled,
the image was created successfully by docker.
Also successfully started new container with this image, but when  trying to access api at localhost or ip,then api is not responding.

For more detail steps follow this url
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2230

Windows Version:Windows 10 Enterprise
Docker for Windows 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513)/Channel:Stable

**Steps**:

1. Created Dotnet Core API app in Visual Studio 2017 community.
2. Selected "Enable Docker Support" checkbox.
3. Dotnet Core project Created.
4. Image got created by Docker through dockerfile.
5. Started new Container with command
   Docker run –it –p 8085:80 coreapidemo:dev
6. API NOT accessible through either localhost or ip
    http://172.22.236.61:8085/api/values
    http://172.22.236.61/api/values
    http://localhost:8085/api/values

**Update 1:**
Thanks @edwin for your help,using

> *docker exec -it mycontainer powershell*

,i can see that directory c:\app does not contain the neccessary code (aspnetapp.dll) to run app.

Then i downloaded image from https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile and started container with it.
Then i able to successfully access the app url at http://localhost:8000.

This means that the visual studio tooling for docker is not building the image properly.Anyone can help?

Comment: you can use also a `-d` to run the docker image detached. What does the docker ps show?

Comment: If we run with -d and then do docker ps ,it shows the container running for few seconds and then it disappears

Comment: sounds like you have a problem in the start script. What does it log when you run without the `-d` ?

Comment: Please visit https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2230 to see the screenshots for more details.It shows all the steps in details

Comment: check `docker logs nameContainer` for errors (and some screenshots are to small to read the content)

Comment: when i run this command,it clears the command prompt window..no output

Comment: can you enter your container and check that the service is running ? (`docker exec -ti containerName (linux:)bash (or windows:)powershell`)

Comment: I was having this exact issue. Visual Studio would build and run the container and run it but it was not possible to access it and also the browser windows would not open. Same exact project worked fine on a different machine. After a reset of the Docker engine to factory defaults and it started working.